# Class method instead of Arrow function

Tags: typescript

I am using a library that has the following definition in the d.ts file.

```
export function read(success?: (data: any, response: Response) => void);
```

I have the following class which works fine if the method is called with an Arrow function.

```
export class App {
  private async getData(): Promise<void> {
    lib.read((data, response) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

However, if I try to pull the method into a class method, it does not work. When I step into the **read** method of library, it says that it is **undefined**.

```
export class App {
  private async onSuccess(data, response) {
    console.log(data);
  }      

  private async getData(): Promise<void> {
    lib.read(this.onSuccess)
  }
}
```

Any ideas why? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Also relevant: [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks! I will spend some time reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use arrow function always, that will help you get the right `this` object:

```
export class App {
  private async onSuccess(data, response) {
    console.log(data);
  }      

  private getData = async (): Promise<void> => {
    lib.read(this.onSuccess)
  }
}
```

Notice the change on `getData` declaration

I would advocate for not using classes but if you do always use `arrow functions` when you need the this coming into play.

Comment: Thanks! Coming from .Net background, it is all a little confusing and feels weird that I have to purely define my methods using "arrow functions" to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: Are there any disadvantage in using arrow functions as class methods? For example, from defining an interface which might make testing/mocking the class harder?

Comment: no disadvantages at all. you will have to transpile the code as it's a newer function but that's something you are probably doing already :) `this` keyword is confusing but arrow functions always get the job done

Comment: @wm_ There is a disadvantage to using "arrow methods" in that they become *properties* on each instance. So, if you have one class that produces a thousand instances from, you get a thousand copies of all methods on that class. So, with three methods, that's three thousand extra objects floating around. When defined as a normal method, the functions are added to the prototype and all instances inherit it from there. So, the same situation as above but using normal methods, you only have three methods in memory in total, with another thousand objects all sharing them.

Comment: there's a small memory drawback but not meaningful enough to discourage its usage. You have to look at each particular scenario. memory is getting garbage collected automatically so when the class is not used it will be fred from the memory.

Comment: if we are to be that picky I wouldn't use classes at all in Javascript, there's just sugar syntax

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback both. @VLAZ If I do not want to use "arrow methods" and want to use class methods, what can I do to fix the code above?

Comment: Actually, after reading your links again, @VLAZ, I realized that I just need to do a ".bind(this)" instead.